# How to inject css into a document via ajax?

Tags: jquery, css

So I get data via jquery's ajax method. The retrieved data looks like:

```
<html>
<head>
  <style>
  body {
     color: red;
     font-weight: bold;
  }

  #someElement {
     color: blue;
     padding: 1em
  }
  </style>
</head>
  <body>
     <div id="header">Super</div>
     <p>blah blah blah</p>
     <div id="footer">Stuff</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

How do I extract the style and insert it into the current document, which is executing the ajax call? I've tried all sorts of jquery incantations but it don't go. I'm now extracting the css via regex but am unsure how to put the css into the current page:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/template.html',
    success: function(data) {
        $("#header").html( $(data).find('#header').html() );
        $("#footer").html( $(data).find('#footer').html() );

        var re  = /<style>((?:[\n\r]|.)+)<\/style>/m;
        var css = re.exec(data);

        // What to do with the css??

        return;
    }
});
```

I initially had a style sheet then simply did the following:

```
    if($.browser.msie) {
        $('head').html(
            '<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://c.this/template.css" type="text/css" />'+
            $('head').html()
        ); 
    }
    else {
        $('head').prepend('<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://c.this/template.css" type="text/css" />');
    }
```

That works except in IE8 it causes some problems.

Comment: It looks like your jQuery selector is looking for an element with an id of `head`. You might want to try with `$("head").html($(data).find("head").html());`

Comment: @josh that part is working fine. I just updated the example so it says #header instead of #head just to show I'm not interested in the head element. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the regex you could use `.filter()` to find the `<style/>` tag, from there simply use `document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]` to append the `HTMLStyleElement`

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "/echo/html/",
    data: {
        html: postHtml
    },
    success: function(data) {
        var style = $(data).filter("style").get(0);
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(style);
        $("#header").html($(data).filter('#header').html());
        $("#footer").html($(data).filter('#footer').html());
    }
});
```

**[Working example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/G2G4b/6/)**

*tested on IE8/9, chrome, firefox*

Comment: That works nicely.I'd like to get the other example working too. Having the css in it's own document then bringing it in using a link tag. However, when I have javascript append the link tag to the head, IE8 does the right thing by rendering the injected link, but it keeps showing that there is one more download. If I click anywhere on the browser then waiting for download disappears. It's annoying.

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't you just create a style tag and insert it into the DOM the same way you would insert any other tag?

```
$('<style type="text/css"></style>')
    .appendTo("head")
    .html("your css text here");
```

*Have not tried this

**EDIT:**

Oh I see you are trying to extract css from an HTML page.  Is there a way you can get just the CSS without having to load another page?

Comment: Yes. However, like I mentioned @T9b, I'd like javascript to do that for me. Is it possible?

Comment: `insertAfter` really should be `appendTo` in the above example.

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to parse a third-party's page, by any chance?

If that is **not** the case, then why don't you just load the CSS independent of the page that calls your ajax. Then it's available to all elemnts on the page - even new ones delivered by ajax.

If you are trying to parse another sites pages, you'll need to develop a proxy service.

Comment: I might have to load the css independent of the ajax fetch. That is actually my back up plan if I cannot get javascript to do it.